# Signing is not valid using RobRichards\XMLSecLibs

Tags: php, xml, digital-signature, xml-dsig

I am currently working on a project requirering signing of xml.

I have used a lot of time on the XMLSecLibs and cannot get it to work properly. It seems like the project is no longer updated and i think my problems can be related to some of the unresolved issues in this project as the signing performed by this library will fail validation.

I use this php-script to make and sign an xml:

```
<?php
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/xmlseclibs-3.1.0/xmlseclibs.php';

// Create XML document
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true; 
$dom->formatOutput = false; 

// Create envelope
$envelope = $dom->createElementNS('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/', 'soapenv:Envelope');

// Create header with MessageID and Action
$header = $dom->createElement('soapenv:Header');

$messageid = $dom->createElement('wsa:MessageID', 'uuid:'.createUuid());
$messageid->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:wsa', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing');
$header->appendChild($messageid);

$action = $dom->createElement('wsa:Action', 'urn:#BilSummariskHent');
$action->setAttribute('xmlns:wsa', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing');
$header->appendChild($action);

// Create body
$body = $dom->createElement('soapenv:Body');

// Create BilSummariskHent
$BilSummariskHent = $dom->createElement('BilSummariskHent');
$BilSummariskHent->setAttribute('xsi:schemaLocation', 'http://rep.oio.dk/tinglysning.dk/service/message/elektroniskakt/1/ http://rep.oio.dk/tinglysning.dk/service/message/elektroniskakt/1/BilSummariskHent.xsd');
$BilSummariskHent->setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://rep.oio.dk/tinglysning.dk/service/message/elektroniskakt/1/');
$BilSummariskHent->setAttribute('xmlns:eakt', 'http://rep.oio.dk/tinglysning.dk/schema/elektroniskakt/1/');
$BilSummariskHent->setAttribute('xmlns:model', 'http://rep.oio.dk/tinglysning.dk/schema/model/1/');
$BilSummariskHent->setAttribute('xmlns:ds', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#');
$BilSummariskHent->setAttribute('xmlns:xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');

$BilIdentifikator = $dom->createElement('model:BilIdentifikator');
$Stelnummer = $dom->createElement('model:Stelnummer', 'WVGZZZ1TZ5W144478');
$BilIdentifikator->appendChild($Stelnummer);
$BilSummariskHent->appendChild($BilIdentifikator);

$body->appendChild($BilSummariskHent);
$envelope->appendChild($header);
$envelope->appendChild($body);
$dom->appendChild($envelope);

// Sign
use RobRichards\XMLSecLibs\XMLSecurityDSig;
use RobRichards\XMLSecLibs\XMLSecurityKey;

$objDSig = new XMLSecurityDSig('');
$objDSig->setCanonicalMethod(XMLSecurityDSig::C14N);

$objDSig->addReference($dom, XMLSecurityDSig::SHA1, array('http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature'), array('force_uri' => true));
$objKey = new XMLSecurityKey(XMLSecurityKey::RSA_SHA1, array('type'=>'private'));

$objKey->loadKey('s2s_87638273_priv.pem', TRUE); // Private key
$objDSig->sign($objKey);

$objDSig->add509Cert(file_get_contents('s2s_87638273_pub.pem')); // Public key
$objDSig->appendSignature($BilSummariskHent);
$outXML = $dom->saveXML();

// Do request
$client = new SoapClient(null, array(
    'location'     => 'https://test.tinglysning.dk/etl/services/ElektroniskAkt/',
    'uri'          => 'https://test.tinglysning.dk/etl/services/',
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
    'encoding'     => 'UTF-8',
    'trace'        => true,
    'local_cert'   => 's2s_87638273_priv.pem'
));

$return = $client->__doRequest($outXML, 'https://test.tinglysning.dk/etl/services/ElektroniskAkt', 'urn:#BilSummariskHent', SOAP_1_1, false);

// Handle the response as needed
echo $return;
?>
```

Resulting in this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <wsa:MessageID xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">uuid:1cda8469-9f78-4c4f-ad37-619807e3ff5d</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:Action xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">urn:#BilSummariskHent</wsa:Action>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <BilSummariskHent xmlns="http://rep.oio.dk/tinglysning.dk/service/message/elektroniskakt/1/" xmlns:eakt="http://rep.oio.dk/tinglysning.dk/schema/elektroniskakt/1/" xmlns:model="http://rep.oio.dk/tinglysning.dk/schema/model/1/" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://rep.oio.dk/tinglysning.dk/service/message/elektroniskakt/1/ http://rep.oio.dk/tinglysning.dk/service/message/elektroniskakt/1/BilSummariskHent.xsd">
      <model:BilIdentifikator>
        <model:Stelnummer>WVGZZZ1TZ5W144478</model:Stelnummer>
      </model:BilIdentifikator>
      <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="ID12345678">
        <SignedInfo>
          <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
          <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
          <Reference URI="">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <DigestValue>nXV07Jwmzx2xPxtuPNqjDHg1qUM=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>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</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
          <X509Data>
            <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
          </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
      </Signature>
    </BilSummariskHent>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I get an signing-error from the service and have been in contact with the supplier of the service i am trying to use. Their response was:

*After trying a number of different approaches to generate and sign the request, I can conclude that xmlseclibs-3.1.0/PHP does not handle the signing correctly. I suspect this is due to poor handling of http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n# as well as some other inconsistencies in the library that I can see on GitHub that others are also struggling with.
I have implemented the logic for signing in Java via the official javax.xml APIs etc. Here, with the same signature parameters, I get a different signature than the one from xmlseclibs-3.1.0, and this is valid. So you should either find an alternative to xmlseclibs-3.1.0 or use something other than PHP.*

Any suggestions on how to fix the signing?

The supplier of the service has confirmed, that the certificate used are exported correct. The certificates are OCES3 (a danish MitID systemcertificate).

Comment: What OS are you using?  Most likely the issue is with the encryption algorithm being used.  It may be the sha1.  Older encryption algorithm are no longer supported because hackers can break the encryption modes.  Your URLs are also old and have old dates.  You are could be failing schema checks, or the encryption algorithm isn't support in older OS.  You did not provide any error messages to help determine the root cause.

Comment: I am using WAMP-server v3.3.3 installed on a Microsoft Windows Server 2022 standard. The full xml is valid in the form it has as the service i am using is backward compatible to when it was established in 2009. I have tried with sha256 and sha512 which both are an option, but the result is the same. The error from the service is not very good which was why i contacted the suppplier of the service. The error is: The calculated hash value: "27721c7d296178f535f95d18f79b2289b0f7ed67", does not match the expected one: "693b1f4da2f8d0214bf63d1c51b33b270b1062cd".

Comment: Why don't you use Powershell to sign.  See : https://gist.github.com/IISResetMe/e0c20ce4fdbab7e19a75255e9d4787d1

Comment: You can use a online signature checker to see if your results or library is right : https://tools.chilkat.io/examinePdfSig

Comment: If i cannot get this issue fixed, i have to look at other options, fx powershell. The online signature checker you are linking to are for pdf-files?

Comment: The tool has many options including XML signature check.

Comment: The signature in the xml i am generating is seen as valid by chilkats validator. When i try to sign using chilkats php-library for this i get an xml nearly identical to the one i am generating using xmlseclibs. The only difference is the SignatureValue. The new xml is also not beeing accepted by the service i am trying to use.

Comment: The encryption algorithm (used for signature) is not working properly.  The issue may be padding mode of the key or the return character.  To make it harder to break often the key is padded with random bits to make a power of 2.  So an encryption key of length 192 with add 64 random bits to the key.  This often creates compatibility issues between java and php because the padding mode default is different in the two programming languages.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50964534/sha-512-with-salt-not-matching-between-java-and-php

Comment: It suddenly becomes very technical. I've read the explanation in the link, but after a lot of googling, I still haven't found out if it's possible to solve or work around this issue in php. Can you answer this?

Comment: See if this Github project give correct signature : https://github.com/robrichards/xmlseclibs#basic-usage

Comment: The question was about about this project (RobRichards\XMLSecLibs) as it does not give correct signature.

Comment: Go to the Library ISSUE website and see if one of the answer solves you issue or contact the developer : https://github.com/robrichards/xmlseclibs/issues

Comment: After extensive research and testing of different theories on why validation fails, a solution emerged. The reason for the lack of validation was that the service did not expect the entire xml to be signed, but only the CarSummarisedRetrieve element. After I signed only this part of the xml, the xml was validated correctly.