# Cipher - AES / CBC/PKCS5padding in PHP

Tags: java, php

I have following code in Java and i want to convert it into PHP.
Can someone tell how I should approach this ?

```
private static Cipher initCipher(final int mode, final String initialVectorString, final String secretKey)

throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException,

InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {

    final SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(), "AES");
    final IvParameterSpec initialVector = new IvParameterSpec(initialVectorString.getBytes());
    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(mode, skeySpec, initialVector);
    return cipher;
}

public static String encrypt(final String dataToEncrypt) {
    String encryptedData = null;
    try {
        // Initialize the cipher
        final Cipher cipher = initCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, iv, secretKey);
        // Encrypt the data
        final byte[] encryptedByteArray = cipher.doFinal(dataToEncrypt.getBytes());
        // Encode using Base64
        encryptedData = (new BASE64Encoder()).encode(encryptedByteArray);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Problem encrypting the data");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return encryptedData;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This thread might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068460/decrypting-php-encrypted-data-on-android

Comment: @BackSlash : i tried to write code in php to encrypt  data . But i got different result  .

Comment: @BinayaBM can you include the PHP code anyway ? That way we can help you figure out kinks and help you understand what you are doing wrong, rather then doing it all for you and you learning nothing.

Comment: PHP has multiple encryption libraries, for example openSSL. And openSSL, among others, is well documented in the official PHP documentation. You should find everything you need there.